# Intent FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP doesn't work like i want

Tags: android, android-intent

I created a custom navigation bar, 4 primary buttons on the bottom of the screen of every activity, and i don't want the user to press the back button and go back to the previous activity but exit the app.
But when i start an activity that is not in the navigation bar i want to return to the previous page. But when i'm in this new Activity and i pressed a navigation button, and i click on the back button, it doesn't quit the app but go back two activities before.

Example : 
Navigation bar activities : A,B,C,D
When i press a button on activity A, i go to activity E, if i press the back button i go back to A, but i press activity B, and i press the back button, i don't exit the app, i don't go to E, but i go to A directly.

the method i created is :

```
private void goTo(Context context, Class<?> classTo) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, classTo);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT); 
    context.startActivity(intent);
    activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    activity.finish();
    Log.i(TAG, "Kill all previous activities");
}
```

I only use this with the navigation bar buttons

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```